# Some questions about php login with session

Tags: php, session, authentication, logout

I was confused in php session
I am developing two different applications in php web with same domain but it didn't allow me to login both.
Here is the sample
In application 1, i set the session like this
`$_SESION['app1']['username'] = 'kevin';` 
In application 2, the session is
`$_SESSION['app2']['username'] = 'k';`
The logout php
`session_start();
session_destroy();`
Both web can be logged in but it only allow me to login one of them at a same period. For example, i logged in to application 1, i could not login to application 2 even if i logged out from application 1. I should wait for some time to login application 2 and then I cannot login o application 1
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `session_destroy()` will destroy everything, both app1 and app2. So if you want to logout from app1 then removing that specifically would be better:

```
unset($_SESSION['app1']);
```

---

The best way to have multiple sessions on the same domain is to set a unique session name:

```
session_name('app1');
```

And do the same in your other app, except calling it `app2`. This will allow you to maintain a unique session in both apps, without having to have a top level app1 and app2 variable. You can also use `session_destroy()` with this method, because the sessions are segregated.

Comment: Thanks, but how about set a session after session_name('app1');? Continue with $SESSION['app1']['username'] = 'kevin';?

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem with set the session name.